# Changing nameservers breaks Google MX records

Tags: dns, gmail, google-workspace, web-hosting

I purchased a domain from [Hover](http://www.hover.com) and I'm setting up Google Apps for Business on it. I went through the steps to change my MX records to [Google's MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en), and everything was working fine. However, when I changed my nameservers to my hosting service, [FreeHosting](https://www.freehosting.com/), my GMail setup in Google Apps stopped working properly.

Is there a step I'm missing, or do my nameservers need to be pointing to Hover at all times for my Google MX records to stay intact?

Comment: Are you certain that only the nameservers were changed? A lot of hosting plans come with control panels that provide DNS. If you comment back with your domain, I'll check it for you.

Comment: @dan thanks for the offer :) It turns out there were also MX records I could modify in the FreeHosting CPanel. I've made the changes and it's working alright.

Comment: No problem - I figured it was probably that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better point your domain first to FreeHosting name server and then on their CP, you can setup the DNS to point your mail service to GMail server. Hope it help

Comment: Yup, I already did this. I wasn't aware they had MX records. Thanks :)